# dynamically making an array of structures

Tags: c, dynamic, structure

how to create an array of structures dynamically?

```
struct arr
{
    int a;
    float b;
} *p;

p = (struct arr *)malloc(2*sizeof(struct arr));

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    scanf("%d %f", &p[i]->a, &p[i]->b);
}

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    printf("%d %f", p[i]->a, p[i]->b);
}
```

this code did not work and produced errors . I edited scanf to this,

```
scanf("%d %f",&(&p[i])->a,&(&p[i])->b);
```

and printf to this,

```
printf(("%d %f",(&p[i])->a,(&p[i])->b);
```

and it worked , but i don't know what exactly is going on.

Comment: `sizeof(2 * struct arr)` is invalid. You want `2* sizeof(struct arr)`

Comment: Good catch @mbratch.  That's going to cause UB too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p + i)`.  There is a dereference operation taking place.  That means you don't want to be using `->`. Just use `.` to access the fields:

```
scanf("%d %f", &p[i].a, &p[i].b);
printf("%d %f",p[i].a, p[i].b);
```

Your solution is equivalent, but more complicated.  `a.b` just happens to be the same as `(&a)->b`.

Comment: i was thinking of array as an adt and thought its implementation is abstract to me.

Answer (score 1):

As @CarlNorum correctly indicated, you're dereferencing the address `p` via `p[i]` but then using a struct member pointer construct. You want the `.`. And fix the `sizeof` as I had commented:

```
struct arr
{
    int a;
    float b;
} *p;

int i;

p = malloc(2*sizeof(struct arr));

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    scanf("%d %f", &p[i].a, &p[i].b);
}

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    printf("%d %f\n", p[i].a, p[i].b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following expression is suspicious, most probably invalid:

```
malloc(sizeof(2 * struct arr));
```

You probably mean this instead:

```
malloc(2 * sizeof(struct arr));
```

I think it's easy to understand why.

Also, if `p` is a `struct arr*`, `p[i]` is a `struct arr`, so you need a `.`, not a `->` to access its members:

```
scanf("%d %f", &(p[i].a), &(p[i].b));
```

And:

```
printf(("%d %f", p[i].a, p[i].b);
```